# Two logging messages recorded as a single line

Tags: python, logging

I'm migrating from using `print()` statements everywhere in my scripts to  a more serious logging system. I'm using the `logging` module to manage the task. There's one thing I can't seem to achieve with it though:

In some cases, I want to create a log entry in two distinct steps, but recorded on the same line. Something that would classically look like this:

```
Initiating procedure... OK
```

In this case, the `OK` part would be recorded only if the task is successful.

I used to achieve that with the following print commands:

```
print('Initiating procedure... ', end="", flush=True)
...
print('OK')
```

Is there a way to achieve a similar thing with the `logging` module? Something like

```
logging.info("First message", end="", flush=True)
...
logging.info("OK")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `BufferingHandler` such as a [`MemoryHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#memoryhandler) together with a custom formatter to achieve what you want. This approach buffers records in memory until flushed, and the flushing writes to a target handler and allows you to potentially merge two logging records into a single output event.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure it is a good idea. I don't think that logs are meant to be used this way. You will often see before your log message informations about date, time, nature of the log message.

Do you really want a line like this :

```
INFO:ROOT 2018-09-01 22:12:13 Initiating procedure... INFO:ROOT 2018-09-01 22:12:17 OK
```

on the same line ?

Often you will parse your logs using other technologies (I often parse logs with awk) and I'm sure I would be very disturbed by that kind of logs.

Comment: This should be a comment, not a suggested answer.

Comment: Many log frameworks offer such functionality, including stdlib - for another example, there is a [`FingersCrossedHandler`](https://logbook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/handlers.html#logbook.FingersCrossedHandler) in logbook. This answer makes the assumption that two log events are emitted, but that is not necessarily the case.